# Is 1st generation GBA bright enough for indoor use?

Tags: game-boy-advance

I am considering buying a Game Boy Advance. I like the 1st generation model, but I don't know if the screen is bright enough for normal indoor use or not.

Is screen brightness likely to be an issue, and if so, what can I do to help with the problem?

Comment: I recommend the Game Boy Advance SP. No accessories to get in the way when it is dark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be seen indoors, but there's no backlighting so it's tough (if not impossible) to see in the dark. There were several [peripherals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004910A8I) released to solve this problem, so if you're dead-set on the original model you do have options. If the model isn't that important, the [Game Boy Advance SP](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000A9Y11) plays the same games, takes up less space, and has a backlit screen.

Answer (score 1):

I can't recommend the SP enough if you're going to play any version of the Game Boy Advance. Slickest design, more durable than it looks too, and of course the backlit screen is a must. I can't envision liking the 1st generation model enough to offset the annoyance by not having a backlit screen. It is playable indoors if you turn on some lighting, however -- I used to use a desk lamp as a kid. That kind of limits the whole portability part to some extent though.

Comment: Personally I found the SP really uncomfortable to hold. The GBA just fit so nicely in your hands *wistful look*

Comment: It actually wouldn't be too hard to make modifications to the case to make it feel like holding the 1st gen model -- basically just attach two plastic handles on either side of the thing, and then the screen could still flip up and down. The whole thing would just be wider as a result. Would take a little effort though. I'd consider it worth it because as far as I know, backlit GBAs don't exist, light attachments are simply not as good, and modding a backlight into a GBA is harder than attaching pieces of plastic to a GBA SP.

Comment: Totally nor what OP asked.

Comment: @Timelord64 "It is playable indoors if you turn on some lighting, however -- I used to use a desk lamp as a kid." It's not exactly a question that requires a long answer.

Comment: Except your talking about the first GBA SP and OP is asking about the first GBA. The GBA and the GBA SP are differant models.

Comment: I'm referring to the GBA, silly. You don't need any lighting to play an SP. Which is why it's good. Logical inference is a powerful tool.